# positioning paragraphs using CSS

Tags: html, css

i have got the bellow code in my index.html file and in my style file i have .block{ float:left; width:33.3%;} could anyone tell me why my output wont separate my paragraphs into 3 sections.

```
<div class="block">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>

        <div class="block">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna al qua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>

        <div class="block">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. running on stack it does exactly what i meant however when i put implement it it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this with flex-box. It's very useful CSS option.
In CSS:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 33%;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I helped, you can give me an upvote, Thanks ;)